# How to avoid 'Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute' when searching

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

What I want to do seems very simple, but each configuration I use gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

I want to pass a string to the controller to search and display attributes of a `List` of `Offices` that are found in a new page.  I am unable to even view the officeSearch page in my browser, I get the aforementioned error.

officeSearch.jsp (Should just be a simple form to pass a String to be searched):

```
<div class="header-divider2">
    <h4>Search</h4>
</div>
<div id="content" class="center">
    <div class="well center square borderless">
        <h1>Location Search</h1>
         <div class="visible-md visible-lg well well-search">
           <form:form method="POST" action="officeSearchResults">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form:input path="searchCriteria" type="text" id="searchCriteria" placeholder="Find a location..." />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
        </form:form>
        </div><!-- visible-md -->
    </div><!-- well center square -->
</div><!-- center -->
```

Here's the controller method that should display the search page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/officeSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String showOfficesSearch() {
    return "officeSearch";
}
```

Here is the jsp that should be displayed after the search is submitted (obviously stubbed for now):

```
<div class="header-divider2">
    <h4>Search Results</h4>
</div>
<div id="content" class="center">
    <div class="well center square borderless">
        <h1>Location Search RESULTS</h1>
    </div><!-- well center square -->
</div><!-- center -->
```

Here is the controller method that's meant to display the previous page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/officeSearchResults", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView search(@ModelAttribute("officeSearchResults") String searchCriteria) {
    List<Office> offices = officeServiceImpl.search(searchCriteria);

    return new ModelAndView("officeSearchResults", "command", offices);
}
```

Please advise on getting this working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form doesn't currently bind to a model attribute, because you haven't added any. By default, ie. when you don't specify a `modelAttribute` or `commandName` attribute (use one or the other)

```
<form:form method="POST" action="officeSearchResults">
```

it will look for a model attribute named `command` to bind to, ie. to resolve the `input` elements by `path`

So just add a model attribute named `command` (or anything else and configure it)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/officeSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String showOfficesSearch(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("command", new WhateverObjectYouWantToBindTo());
    return "officeSearch";
}
```

Alternatively, you can build your `<form>` and `<input>` elements yourself instead of using Spring's `form` tag support.